# Performance problems with Redis/Spring Data Redis

Tags: performance, spring-boot, redis, jedis, spring-data-redis

I have a performance problem in my Spring Boot application when it's communicating with Redis that I was hoping someone with expertise on the topic could shed some light on.

**Explanation of what I'm trying to do**
In short, my application I have 2 nested maps and 3 maps of lists which I want to save to Redis and load back into the application when the data is needed. The data in the first nested map is fairly big, with several levels of non-primitive data types (and lists of these). At the moment I have structured the data in Redis using repositories and Redis Hashes, with repositories A, B, and C, and two different ways of lookup on id for the primary datatype (`MyClass`) in A. B and C holds data that is referenced from a value in A (with the `@Reference` annotation).

**Performance analysis**
Using JProfiler, I have found that the bottleneck is somewhere between my call to `a.findOne()` and the end of reading the response from Redis (before any conversion from `byte[]` to `MyClass` has taken place). I have looked at the slowlog on my Redis server to check for any slow and blocking actions and found none. Each `HGETALL` command in Redis takes 400μs on average (for a complete hash in A, including finding the referenced hashes in B and C). What strikes me as weird is that timing the `a.findOne()` call takes from 5-20ms for one single instance of `MyClass`, depending on how big the hashes in B and C are. A single instance has on average ~2500 hash fields in total when references to B and C are included. When this is done ~900 times on the for the first nested map, I have to wait 10s to get all my data, which is way too long. In comparison, the other nested nested map, which has no references to C (the biggest part of the data), is timed to ~10μs in Redis and <1ms in Java.

Does this analysis seem like normal behavior when the Redis instance is run locally on the same 2015 MacBook Pro as the Spring Boot application? I understand that it will take longer for the complete `findOne()` method to finish than the actual `HGETALL` command in Redis, but I don't get why the difference is this big. If anyone could shed some light on the performance of the stuff going on under the hood in the Jedis connection code, I'd appreciate it.

**Examples of my data structure in Java**

```
@RedisHash("myClass")
public class MyClass {

@Id
private String id;

private Date date;
private Integer someValue;

@Reference
private Set<C> cs;

private someClass someObject;
private int somePrimitive;
private anotherClass anotherObject;

@Reference
private B b;
```

Excerpt of class C (a few primitives removed for clarity):

```
@RedisHash("c")
public class C implements Comparable<BasketValue>, Serializable {

@Id
private String id;

private EnumClass someEnum;
private aClass anObject;
private int aNumber;
private int anotherNumber;
private Date someDate;

private List<CounterClass> counterObjects;
```

Excerpt of class B:

```
@RedisHash("b")
public class B implements Serializable {

@Id
private int code;

private String productCodes;
private List<ListClass> listObject;
private yetAnotherClass yetAnotherObject;
private Integer someInteger;
```

Comment: can you provide a sample of your domain type + data? Conversion may take some time depending on the domain model and amount of data in place. Not knowing the specific case/model/structure of the data, having hashes with 2500 keys that should get mapped into a single domain type do not seem to be a good fit for the repository approach - maybe going straight through `RedisTemplate.opsForHash` using a `Jackson` based `RedisSerializer` would be the better choice here.

Comment: @ChristophStrobl I have edited my post to include some of my data structure. I agree with you that Redis repositories may not be the best solution here, and I'm suspecting the biggest problem here being that every class includes lists with new non-primitives, which is why I end up with so many hash fields for single instance of `MyClass`. I do however, think it is weird that it takes so much time to read this, because the conversion comes after what JProfiler showed to take up 80% of the time. Could you be more specific in what kind of data structuring you would use in Redis?

Comment: can you share your profiling results so that I can potentially spot the code path consuming that amount of time. As you're saying results show that it's not the conversion itself.

Comment: As Cristoph mentioned, I'd also suggest to rewrite the code with plain `RedistTemplate` using pipelines. Redis Repository query may be not what you really want to use in the given case.